# IN Python spyder not showing output in console

Tags: python

There is no output after running the file and I keep getting the same message

`runfile('E:/Python/tup.py', wdir='E:/Python')`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmTn0.png)
I'm new in python so I don't know what I have done wrong.. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

If you use python shell you can see the variable by calling its name, here in IDE you should use print syntax to see your variable  in console.

```
print(nums[1])
```

Output:

```
5
```